# Is it possible to create WYSIWYG editor using monaco?

Tags: wysiwyg, codemirror, monaco-editor

Just like how https://laobubu.net/HyperMD/#README.md did in codemirror.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible. Monaco is a **code editor**, created for helping to write source code in any form. It has no support for multiple fonts, tables etc., nor can you draw arbitrary graphics in it (even though there are means to embed someting, but that's a different thing).

Comment: Maybe a "restricted code editor", so it can be of high performance. I take deeper look into hypermd these days, and find that Code mirror is a code editor too, but it gives users many opportunities to create rich content, you can create "mark" with any HTML elements. That is why someone can creates hypermd with it.